# Imagick cropImage issue php

Tags: php, imagick

I've an image of size **1353 x 451**, When I try to crop it to **1350 x 451**, using Imagick function **cropImage**, I get a wrong output.

It returns an image of dimension **1350 x 236** instead of **1350 x 451**.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  $im = new Imagick();
  $im->readImage( $orig_img_path );
  $im->cropImage((int) $w, (int) $h, (int) $x, (int) $y);
  $im->writeImage($final_img_path);
```

Where **$orig_img_path** contains the actual image and I'm writing the final image at **$final_img_path**.

Is there any way, I can force proper cropping of image as per given dimensions?

Comment: Are you sure of the actual values being passed to the function? Have you tried intval() instead of casting them to (int)?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure about it. I dumped it and it gives me integer and they are correct.
There is nothing in documentation even.

Comment: Can you post the image you're using and the values for w, h, x, y?